# I want to make a form that changes when you select a (radio) box using fieldset and selection

Tags: html, forms, selection, fieldset

I'm trying to make a questionnaire using only HTML5. After the user makes the decision between Option 1 and option 2 I want a different form to appear on the same page.

This is the code i have now

```
<h1> Choose an option </h1>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="keuze" value="project" checked>Option 1
  <input type="radio" name="keuze" value="stage">Option 2
    </form>
```

If the user checks one of the boxes i want a different form to appear depending on what box they checked

Is there a way to do it with  and

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic way of how I would do it:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="keuze" value="project" checked/>Option 1
    <div>Form 1</div>
    </br>
    <input type="radio" name="keuze" value="stage" />Option 2
    <div>Form 2</div>
</form>

div {
    display:none;
}
input:checked + div {
    display:block;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h6p93f6e/1/)

Comment: Is there also a way to do it with <fieldset> and <selection>?

Comment: Can you provide the html structure you have in mind?